# reading and printing an integer in Qtspim

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

Before i explain what's going on i'm working with Qtspim.The program is simple: All it does is read an integer (from the user) and output the number that was typed in.This is the code:

```
###################################################
# text segment                  #
###################################################
 .text
 .globl __start

__start:

    li $v0,4
    la $a0,message
    syscall

    li $v0, 5      #read_int#
    syscall
    move $a0,$v0

    li $v0, 1      #print_int#
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall
###################################################
# data segment                  #
###################################################
.data
message: .asciiz "please enter in a single number:"
###################################################
#                    #
# End of File                   #
#                    #
```

and this is the output:

```
please enter in a single number:0
```

*Note:when you type the input, it doesn't print what you typed in.So the 0 is the output of the program*

Comment: note:i know that there are like hundrents of tutorials on how to read/print an integer but i believe my program is correct.I think the fault can be found somewhere on the mips settings.I had a friend execute it and it worked for them

Comment: Did you single-step your code in QtSPIM's debugger?  I don't see an problem either, https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html shows those are the right numbers and registers for those MARS/SPIM syscalls.  So I wonder if you maybe forgot to save your file before reloading it in SPIM or something like that...  Single-stepping in the debugger should rule that out.  Especially if this copy/paste of it worked for a friend who tried it.

Comment: @PeterCordes wish that was the problem :// I always save my file (as .s) and always reinitialize and load file. Also working with F10  (single-step) and no errors pop up :(

Comment: I also downloaded all the versions (new or old) util the '19 one, reinitialized and loaded the file and every single version outputs this...

Comment: Check your QtSPim options: Simulator->Settings->MIPS-> Memory Mapped I/O.  If checked, uncheck it and if unchecked already tell us.

Comment: How are you even managing to assemble and run this code? The startup code in QtSPIM 9.1.12 expects your program's entry point to be named `main`, and it doesn't like the `__start` label name.

Comment: Ok, if I uncheck the "Load exception handler" option (which also disables the default startup code) then your code assembles and runs. And it seems to work fine to me (it outputs the number that I input).

Comment: @ErikEidt i unchecked it, run the program and the output was still 0.. :/ The only diffrence was that it displayed my input this time

Comment: @Michael i had it unchecked already when i asked this question.So to sum it up the output is still 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah turns out i didn't press enter after my input.....yeeahhhh........